# Cannot resolve an intent for Android programming

Tags: java, android, android-intent, launcher

I am getting a list of ResolveInfo when I do `getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(myIntent, 0)` but I am not able to resolve that `myIntent` in `startActivity(myIntent)`.

I'm currently following the introductory examples on the Android developer's website.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent("MY_CUSTOM_INTENT");
List<ResolveInfo> apps = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(myIntent, 0);
if(apps.size() > 0){
    startActivity(myIntent);}
```

I've checked the output of `System.out.println(apps.size())` and this returns 6, which is as expected.

For the other applications that I would like to start with myIntent, they are just regular HelloWorld application with

```
...
<intent-filter>
...
<action android:name="MY_CUSTOM_INTENT"/>
...
</intent-filter>
...
```

that one line added in the intent-filter.  I don't get why it is flawless in querying activities that can resolve myIntent while when really trying to resolve myIntent, it is starting a error (it is saying there is no app that can perform such intent).

Comment: I've resolved this problem: Somehow, when I add a custom action(my_custom_intent) in between of the default action (action_main) and category (category_launcher) in the AndroidManifest.XML, the queryIntentActivities picked them up when I put my_custom_intent, while the intent actually wasn't interpreted to be resolved by any of them.  I just added another intent-filter with just my_custom_intent and category_default and set the intent with those two when looking for activities and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

can you give a try like below

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent("MY_CUSTOM_INTENT");
List<ResolveInfo> apps = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(myIntent, 0);
 if(apps.size() > 0){
 myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 startActivity(myIntent);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Intent class.  The constructor you are using has the following comment:

> Create an intent with a given action.  All other fields (data, type,
>   class) are null.  Note that the action *must* be in a
>   namespace because Intents are used globally in the system -- for
>   example the system VIEW action is android.intent.action.VIEW; an
>   application's custom action would be something like
>   com.google.app.myapp.CUSTOM_ACTION.

HTH

Comment: The thing is that regardless of using the system VIEW action or that com.google.somethign CUSTOM ACTION, when I set my intent to have "MY_CUSTOM_INTENT" and call queryIntentActivities method with that intent, I receive 6 applications(or activities) available with such intent, which is what I tried to do so.  When I startActivity(myIntent), however, it doesn't start any activity.